Error: "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression" in trigger function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_user_grade()
 RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
 BEGIN
  IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
    IF EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM courses c
            WHERE c.user_id = NEW.user_id
            AND c.subject = NEW.subject
            AND c.course_code = NEW.course_code
            AND c.credits = NEW.credits) then
            IF (SELECT c.grade FROM courses c WHERE c.user_id = NEW.user_id AND c.subject = NEW.subject AND c.course_code = NEW.course_code
                AND c.credits = NEW.credits) < NEW.grade THEN
                UPDATE users
                SET grade = grade + (NEW.grade * NEW.credits) - (SELECT c.grade * c.credits FROM courses c
                                                            WHERE c.user_id = NEW.user_id AND c.subject = NEW.subject AND c.course_code = NEW.course_code AND c.credits = NEW.credits AND c.grade < NEW.grade)
                WHERE id = NEW.user_id;
            ELSE
               RETURN NULL;
            END IF;
    ELSE        
        IF NEW.graded IS TRUE AND NEW.grade IS NOT NULL THEN
            UPDATE users
            SET grade = COALESCE(grade + (NEW.grade * new.credits),0),
                credits = COALESCE(credits + new.credits, 0),
                counted_credits = COALESCE(counted_credits + new.credits, 0)
            WHERE id = NEW.user_id;
        ELSIF NEW.graded IS FALSE AND (NEW.grade = 1 OR NEW.grade = 0) 
THEN
            UPDATE users
            SET credits = COALESCE(credits + new.credits, 0)
            WHERE id = NEW.user_id;
        END IF;
    END IF;
  END IF;
RETURN NEW;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

I can't really spot the error in my code, and it is giving me this error

more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

I don't know how to fix this error, everything seems logical.

One of the subqueries returns more than one row (The EXISTS one is fine.) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Probably in the "IF (SELECT c.grade FROM courses c... That could return more than one row but it's doing a boolean check and needs to only return one.

Please also show the trigger definition (CREATE TRIGGER script), the (relevant part of the) table definitions of tables courses and users. And always your version of Postgres.

This should fix the reported error (plus it only reads from table courses once instead of three times:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_user_grade()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE  -- !!!
   _grade int;    -- use matching data type!
   _credits int;  -- use matching data type!
BEGIN
   IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
      SELECT c.grade, c.credits
      INTO    _grade,  _credits  -- !!!
      FROM   courses c
      WHERE  c.user_id     = NEW.user_id
      AND    c.subject     = NEW.subject
      AND    c.course_code = NEW.course_code
      AND    c.credits     = NEW.credits
      ORDER  BY c.grade DESC NULLS LAST  -- deterministic !!!
      LIMIT  1;                          -- single result !!!!!

      IF FOUND THEN  -- !
         IF _grade < NEW.grade THEN
            UPDATE users
            SET    grade = grade
                         + NEW.grade * NEW.credits
                         -    _grade *    _credits
            WHERE  id = NEW.user_id;
         ELSE
            RETURN NULL;
         END IF;
      ELSIF NEW.graded
      AND   NEW.grade IS NOT NULL THEN
         UPDATE users
         SET    grade           = COALESCE(grade + NEW.grade * NEW.credits, 0)
              , credits         = COALESCE(credits + NEW.credits, 0)
              , counted_credits = COALESCE(counted_credits + NEW.credits, 0)
         WHERE  id = NEW.user_id;
      ELSIF NEW.graded IS FALSE
      AND  (NEW.grade = 1 OR NEW.grade = 0) THEN
         UPDATE users
         SET    credits = COALESCE(credits + NEW.credits, 0)
         WHERE  id = NEW.user_id;
      END IF;
   END IF;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;

For lack of explanation, I pick the single, highest courses.grade - if any.
There is not enough info to tell if the trigger function is sensible otherwise.
